# Loop to find space with python

Tags: python, loops, space

```
c = "ab cd ef gf"
n = []
for x in c:
    if x == " ":
        d = c.find(x)
        n.append(d)
print(n)
```

I want this code to give me something like this. [2,5,8]
But instead it is giving me this. [2,2,2]

Please help me find the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find()` will find the first instance, so it always finds the space at index 2. You could keep track of the index as you go with `enumerate()` so you don't need `find()`:

```
c = "ab cd ef gf"
n = []
for i, x in enumerate(c):
    if x == " ":      
        n.append(i)
print(n)
```

Alternatively as a list comprehension:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(c) if x == " "]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be:

```
space_idxs = []
for idx, char in enumerate(s):
    if char == ' ':
        space_idxs.append(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because **find**(pattern) function returns the first entry of the pattern. Let me supplement your code with required function **find_all**(string, pattern)

```
def find_all(string, pattern):
    start = 0
    indexes = []
    for char in string:
        start = string.find(pattern, start)
        if start == -1: 
            return indexes
        indexes.append(start)
        start += len(pattern) 

c = "ab cd ef gf"
n = []
n = find_all(c, " ")
print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
c="ab cd ef gh"
x=" "
print([t for t, k in enumerate(c) if k==x])
```

it will return [2,5,8]

in your code you are searching for the index value of x in c, three times:

1. in the for loop you are taking all the characters in your string one by one,
2. the if loop validates if it is a space
3. now when the character is a space it enters the if loop
4. the find command will look for x (space) in c
   which is 2
   the same is repeated three times and are appended to n

if you want it in a list:

```
n=([t for t, k in enumerate(c) if k==x])
```